# MongoDB system.profile collection: no data for "insert" operations?

Tags: mongodb, logging, profiling

I've configured my MongoDB 2.0.2 instance (update: also tried this with a v2.2.0 instance) to log all operations to the `system.profile` collection (i.e., `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`) and am trying to see exactly what data is being inserted by an application when it calls save() for a **new** doc.

*I can see the 'insert' operations in the `system.profile` collection, but it doesn't include the data that's being inserted. Why is that?*

In contrast, update operations recorded in `system.profile` have an 'updateobj' property which shows the data.

Here's an example from a 2.2.0 instance. As you can see, the profile log includes an entry for the update with 'updateObj' data. The insert, however, doesn't have any info about what was inserted.

```
> use test;
switched to db test
> db.getProfilingStatus();
{ "was" : 2, "slowms" : 100 }
> show collections;
cartoons
system.indexes
system.profile
> db.foobar.insert({ "blah": true });
> db.foobar.update({ "blah": true }, { $set: { blerg: 1 } });
> db.system.profile.find({ ns:"test.foobar" });
{
  "ts": ISODate("2012-09-25T20:37:40.287Z"),
  "op": "insert",
  "ns": "test.foobar",
  "keyUpdates": 0,
  "numYield": 0,
  "lockStats": {
    "timeLockedMicros": {
      "r": NumberLong(0),
      "w": NumberLong(2028)
    },
    "timeAcquiringMicros": {
      "r": NumberLong(0),
      "w": NumberLong(10)
    }
  },
  "millis": 2,
  "client": "127.0.0.1",
  "user": ""
}{
  "ts": ISODate("2012-09-25T20:38:11.454Z"),
  "op": "update",
  "ns": "test.foobar",
  "query": {
    "blah": true
  },
  "updateobj": {
    "$set": {
      "blerg": 1
    }
  },
  "nscanned": 1,
  "moved": true,
  "nmoved": 1,
  "nupdated": 1,
  "keyUpdates": 0,
  "numYield": 0,
  "lockStats": {
    "timeLockedMicros": {
      "r": NumberLong(0),
      "w": NumberLong(1797)
    },
    "timeAcquiringMicros": {
      "r": NumberLong(0),
      "w": NumberLong(9)
    }
  },
  "millis": 1,
  "client": "127.0.0.1",
  "user": ""
}
```

Comment: what version? earlier versions of 2.0.x had a bug that meant slow ops were not logged with their query details - fixed in later builds

Comment: 2.0.2. I set the profiling level to "2" which, if I understand correctly, should mean that it logs everything--not just slow ops...

Comment: 2.0.2 definitely had the bug I am thinking of - I think it was fixed around 2.0.4.  The logging mechanism would be the same for both, so it could easily happen here too (was just noticed in the slow ops logging first).  Can you try an upgrade to 2.0.7 and see if the queries then show up?

Comment: Will upgrade in the next week and report back--thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for misleading you originally, it turns out that this is intentional (my original response was related to this being a bug with logging slow ops).  The idea behind not doing this is that you would just double the write load automatically by turning this on, since you are effectively just writing the same information (actually a little more) twice.

Since the idea with profiling is usually to troubleshoot a performance issue, this has not been implemented as the default.  However, it has been requested as an option:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3848

As you can see, it is not yet scheduled for a version, but votes and comments outlining why this would be useful do help when deciding what gets implemented.

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to follow-up... I upgraded to Mongo 2.2.0 and confirmed that the issue still exists (see updated question above with complete example).